# Is it possible to create a binary extension that can run on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, google-chrome-os

Chrome supports binary extensions on all platforms.
But I cannot decide whether Chrome OS supports them too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they are disabled on purpose.

See [this](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-os-dev/browse_thread/thread/5a8a923b905807e4?pli=1), [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=10895&can=1&q=NPAPI&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone), [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=4194&can=1&q=NPAPI&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone).

Answer (score 1):

They don't support NPAPI, but they do support the new native client architecture NaCL.

For more information regarding the difference:

http://dev.chromium.org/nativeclient/getting-started/getting-started-background-and-basics

If your binary extension uses PPAPI rather than NPAPI, it will definitely work on Chrome OS.