# PPAPI Plugin and Chromium OS

Tags: sql, npapi, browser-plugin, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I'm looking to use Chromium OS for a specific business application, but I need access to local serial and USB ports. My reading of the Chromium docs says NPAPI plugins are not supported in Chrome OS, only PPAPI (Pepper). I'm a bit confused about PPAPI, as all docs talk about this in the context of Native Client, which as it's a sandboxed environment, cannot access local resources.

So my basic question is: Is it possible to write a PPAPI browser plugin that will work like a regular NPAPI browser plugin to access local resources?

Comment: No. Proof: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083471/55267

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no. NPAPI plugins are on the way out, Native Client is a sandboxed environment, and Pepper's interfaces are designed to mirror those available elsewhere on the web platform (e.g. Javascript). So a good place to look for future interfaces would be draft web standards and HTML5/JS addons, e.g. for gamepads (https://wiki.mozilla.org/GamepadAPI) or cameras (http://developers.whatwg.org/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html )